# How to update state of component from a container?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle

I have this graph that presents weekly data or monthly depending on which button the user presses. I also have my Saga, Redux, Container, and component set up. Until now, I have had two values in my props, one for monthly data and one for weekly. However, I want the graph to present data depending on what dates the user inputs. So, the props need to update every time the user inputs two new dates and clicks go.

Currently, I am able to call my get function and retrieve data using my container and update the state in my container. However, I am not sure how to get my graph to update the data it presents. How can I get it so that when the user inputs two dates and pushes the button, the component notices a change in the props and updates? I thought about using ComponentWillUpdate etc but I don't know if that will work/where to start and if I need more than just componentWillUpdate.

Component:

Constructor ->

```
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        startDate: 'userInputStart',
        endDate: 'userInputEnd,
      }

      this.handleMClick = this.handleMClick.bind(this);
      this.handleWClick = this.handleWClick.bind(this);
    }
```

where data is called for graph ->

```
       let data = this.props.graphData;
       return(
          <div className='graph'>
            <div className='buttons'>
              <button className={this.state.monthly} onClick={this.onClickMonthly()}>Monthly</button>
              <button className={this.state.weekly} onClick={this.handleWClick.bind(this)}>Weekly</button>
            </div>
            <div className='graphData'>
            <LineChart width={730} height={250} data={data}
              margin={{ top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}>
              <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
              <XAxis dataKey="2"/>
              <YAxis />
              <Tooltip />
              <Legend />
              <Line type="monotone" dataKey="5" stroke="#8884d8" />
            </LineChart>
            </div>
          </div>
         );
```

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may pass a redux dispatcher into your graph component and update the dates (which will reflect the graphData) through the prop whenever users input the date range and click the submit button.

```js
--------- STEP 1
// your container file which imports the graph component like the example below
class YourGraphContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // do your logic to update the graphData in `yourReduxDispatcher`
    return <Graph graphData={graphData} updateDateRange={yourReduxDispatcher} />
  }
}

--------- STEP 2
// then in your graphComponent.jsx
class Graph extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      startDate: 'userInputStart',
      endDate: 'userInputEnd',
    }
  }

  updateRange = () => {
    const { startDate, endDate } = this.state;
    this.props.updateDateRange(startDate, endDate);
  }

  render() {
    <DateRangePicker
      startDate={this.state.startDate}
      endDate={this.state.endDate}
      onDatesChange={({ startDate, endDate }) => this.setState({ startDate, endDate 
      })}
    />
    <button onClick={this.updateRange}>Update Graph Data</button>
  }
}
```